# database - need some feedbacks about the conception

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I work on a project in LARAVEL  to manage a sport club .

I'm actually making the database and I'm not sure at this point ,

I have a table `users(id , name , login , password , club_id )`

i have a `clubs (id , name , adresse , ... )`  table also

**my problem is , the club needs to pay every year a cotisation payment to the federation .**

I created a table `cotisation_club (id , name_cotisation , price )`
who give the price of the cotisation .

Should I put a foreign key from `cotisation_club` to my table `clubs` ?

I want incluse a column "`expire_at`" and also a column "payed" to send to the user when the cotisation is expired after the payment . where should I put this datas ?

Someone have an idea of the "BEST" database model to manage this ?

Comment: You need to normalize this schema. Have separate relational tables to handle the ids so for instance get club_id out of the users table and have a separate table like user_clubs and collect the user id and club id. It will give you so much more flexibility in the future, trust me.

Comment: thanks for your reply , but what about the cotisation_club ?